# MFC OnTimer receiving extra events from somewhere else

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC Application where I'm using the ON_WM_TIMER.

The first 1-2 minutes, I fire up the timer with

```
m_nIDEvent = SetTimer( 234, 500, NULL );
```

This is working perfectly, but after 2-3 minutes of running the application, I'm getting another event that I have no idea where is it coming from every 100ms or so.

So, I have 
    void SomeClass::OnTimer(UINT event)
    {
      char str[100];
      sprintf_s(str, "event = %d\n", event);
    }

At first it only prints out the event #234, but after 2-3 minutes it starts displaying some events from 430-432. Any ideas?

I tried putting a breakpoint at afxwin2.inl ( where SetTimer is is defined ) and with the event I put it stops there as intended, but not with the other random event.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Old browser not allowing me to edit it, but there's a print statement on OnTimer that I did not add.

Comment: Windows uses timers internally to achieve certain visual effects. Can you be more specific as to 'SomeClass' you refer to?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I have a class called Viewer2, which is a base class of CRichEditView. Right now I'm keeping it simple only adding some text to the CRichEditView using WM_TIMER.

Answer (score 1):

This is the nature of the Windows timer. All timer events get handled by the single message WM_TIMER, and your `OnTimer` function should check for the specific events it can handle. Some Windows components can generate their own timer requests, and those won't go through the MFC SetTimer function to trigger your breakpoint.

Comment: I just noticed this, for instance I removed the SetTimer event from my code. This problem is repeatable when I Left click and drag on the RichEditView window, which I guess it would be an expected response from MFC, the problem is that it's getting stuck and continues to call this even when I'm not using left click/drag.